# How do I make react native icon sizes flexible?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building a ReactNative iOS/Android app using Expo, and I want to use vector icons for some of my artwork.  The issue is the artwork in question needs to scale with the view, I don't want it too small on some devices or too large on another.

With an image, in theory, I could use `style = { { width:'100%', aspectRatio: 1 } }` to force things to behave.  (In theory I say, because it doesn't work consistently)

Is there anything similar for vector icons?  Right now I'm just picking a size number that more-or-less works, but I don't want it to stop working on a given size, and it just seems that I'm repeating the mistake of using fixed widths that broke some other screens until I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'Dimensions':
Import Dimensions From react native and then use it to set the size of your image

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const logo = require("logo.png");
```

in render:

then you set the image style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
    height: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.65,
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.65,
    marginLeft: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.2
  }
})
```